# How to save amimations on the "asset browser"

Tags: animation, rigging, asset-browser

i have a character just rigged and i have just save a lot of "pose" of him on the "asset browser" to create a library, but i would like also to create an animation library. I have tried to save an animation going on the "outliner" over the "armature" right-click on the animation section chosing "mark as asset", but it doesn't work. Do you know a way to do this? Discovering this greatly speed up my work :)

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbzBt60dhY8&t=1720s) is the information on it in Blender 3.5 and it doesn't seem to have made it into 3.6 either.

Comment: Quich update: CGDive (the author of that video) added [another one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUa1milHsOo) a couple of days later detailing a hack to be able to use it in 3.5.